# Css grid-row for repeated rows

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-grid

I want to make a gallery using css grid layout:

[image]

But I can not repeat grid-row for the next 6 div elements. I use css `nth:child()` element, but it does not work properly. Here is my source code:

```css
.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery .work-image:nth-child(6n+1) {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2n+1;
}

.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery .work-image:nth-child(6n+2) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2n+1;
}

.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery .work-image:nth-child(6n+3) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2n+1 / span 2;
}

.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery .work-image:nth-child(6n+4) {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 2n+1;
}

.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery .work-image:nth-child(6n+5) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2n;
}

.wa-works-page .content .works-gallery .work-image:nth-child(6n) {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 2n;
}
```

Here my html.In wordpress acf repeter loop in every step I show one image.

```html
<div class="container content">
  <div class="works-gallery">
 <?php 
  if( have_rows('works_gallery') ):

    while ( have_rows('works_gallery') ) : the_row();
 ?>   
  <div class="work-image">
   <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image')['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo get_sub_field('image')['alt'];?>">
  </div>
       
<?php  endwhile;
     
endif;
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add html?

Comment: <div class="container content">
    <div class="works-gallery">
     <?php 
      if( have_rows('works_gallery') ):

       while ( have_rows('works_gallery') ) : the_row();
     ?>   
         <div class="work-image">
          <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image')['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo get_sub_field('image')['alt'];?>">
       </div>
       
     <?php  endwhile;
     
      endif;
     ?>
    </div>
    
   </div>

Comment: Can you please add it to your question?

Comment: I add html code.